# Is there any free tool for converting html page to image?

Tags: java, html, image, snapshot

I'd like to take a snapshot of html and save it as image for visualization. Does anyone know any tools that I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs the simplest may be to simply take a screenshot while you are looking at the webpage.

Other than that, searching for "html pdf" gets tons of options.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking just for a tool, there are some plugins for chrome and for firefox that can the for you.

check this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki